# How to use decimal computations inside parentheses to compute the height of an image?

Tags: graphics, calculations, size, calc

I have the following LaTeX file which does not compile:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\AFiveHeight{210mm}

\newcommand\BodyToLayoutRatio{0.7}

\newcommand\Margin{3mm}

\newcommand\MarginRatio{0.67}

\begin{document}

  \includegraphics[height = \AFiveHeight * (1 - \BodyToLayoutRatio) / (1 + \MarginRatio) - \Margin * 2]{EAN.png}

\end{document}
```

This computation should ensure that the EAN bar code fits neatly in the bottom margin of the back cover without encroaching on the body area that is intended for the cover text. I could, of course, compute the height by hand and hard-code it, but if it's possible I'd like to avoid it so that I can change the `\BodyToLayoutRatio` or `\MarginRatio` at any time and have the document still look as intended without any further changes.

Is it possible and if yes, then what would be the correct syntax to perform this computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\fpeval` with the `xfp` package.

Lengths will be automatically converted to unit points, so you can just add `pt` at the end.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand\AFiveHeight{210mm}
\newcommand\BodyToLayoutRatio{0.7}
\newcommand\Margin{3mm}
\newcommand\MarginRatio{0.67}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[
  height =
  \fpeval{\AFiveHeight * (1 - \BodyToLayoutRatio) / (1 + \MarginRatio) - \Margin * 2}pt
]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.